# Ejecutar una función dentro de una celda tabla Vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertia.js

Estoy mostrando una tabla en Vue.js todo funciona perfecto pero necesito mostrar en una columna el estado de una factura, el estado es traído a travez del consumo de un WebService, no se como seria la mejor forma de hacerlo intente hacerlo de esta manera, pero no estoy muy seguro de que lo este haciendo de manera correcta, y no funciona en lo absoluto , no pone ningún valor en el html cuando se ejecuta la función, aquí mi código:

```
getStatus(invoice){
  axios.get(`/electronic_billing/national/invoices/get_status_factible/${invoice}`).then(resp => {
     if(resp.data == 'true'){
       return '<h6 class="text-theme-9">Procesado correctamente</h6>';
     }else{
        return '<h6 class="text-theme-6">Pendiente</h6>';
     }
   }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
   });
}
```

y en la tabla cuando la recorro hago esto:

```
 <td class="w-40 border-b">{{ getStatus(row.numero) }}</td>
```

Alguna idea de como lo debo hacer de manera correcta, soy un poco novato en Vue.js y no veo mucha info de como puedo hacer esto, de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: `getStatus` y `getStatusFactible` son lo mismo me imagino?

Comment: Gracias por la correccion , ya edite el post

Comment: `getStatus()` está dentro de `methods` o `computed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create una constante con state:

```
const [numero, setNumero] = useState([]);
```

si estas usando component funcional, puedes usar useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);
```

entonces crea una funcion loadData()

```
loadData(){
    setNumero(getStatus(invoice)); // arriba no olvides importar la funcion getStatus
}
```

esta tu funcion puedes ponerla en un service

```
getStatus(invoice){
  axios.get(`/electronic_billing/national/invoices/get_status_factible/${invoice}`).then(resp => {
     if(resp.data == 'true'){
       return '<h6 class="text-theme-9">Procesado correctamente</h6>';
     }else{
        return '<h6 class="text-theme-6">Pendiente</h6>';
     }
   }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
   });
}
```

ahora ya tienes el valor en la constante numero

```
<td class="w-40 border-b">{{ getStatus(numero) }}</td>
```